# argument of type Account is not assignable to parameter type any[] angular 6

Tags: angular6

hayy my **account.service.ts** getting this error

> argument of type Account is not assignable to parameter of type any[]

and im currently using angular 6"

**this my code , account.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireList, AngularFireObject, AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Account } from '../models/Account';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class AccountService {
  accounts:AngularFireList<any[]>;
  account:Observable<any>;
  accountRef:AngularFireObject<any>;

  constructor(public af:AngularFireDatabase) { 
    this.accounts = this.af.list('/users') as AngularFireList<Account[]>;
    this.account = this.accounts.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
      return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
    });
  }
  getAccounts(){ 
    return this.account;
  }  

 newAccount(account:Account){
  this.accounts.push(account); ==> **Error code on account**

  } 

  getAccount(id:string){
    this.accountRef = this.af.object('/users/'+id) as AngularFireObject<Account>;
   return this.accountRef;
  }
  updateAccount(id:string, account:Account){
    return this.accounts.update(id, account); ==> *Error code on line account*
  }
  deleteAccount(id:string){
    return this.accounts.remove(id);
  }
}
```

**my Model, Account.ts**

```
export interface Account{
    key?:string;
    email?:string;
    nama?:string;
    fakultas?:string;
    jenisKelamin?:string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to make it any array of any `AngularFireList<any[]>;` just simply make it of any type as `AngularFireList<any>;`
Any itself mean of any type like observales , array of int etc .

Comment: i did remove 'any' on accounts:AngularFireList but im getting another error **Generic type 'AngularFireList<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).**

Comment: Please see my answer once again